# Creating table python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set in excel. A sample of the data is given below. Each row contains a number of items; one item in each column. The data has no headers either.

```
a b a d

g z f d a

e

dd gg dd g f r t
```

want to create a table which should look like below. It should count the items in each row and display the count by the row. I dont know apriori how many items are in the table.

```
row# a b d g z f e dd gg r t

1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

2 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

4 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 1
```

I am not an expert in python and any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_dummies` + `sum`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=range(100)).stack() # setup to account for missing values
df.str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

   a  b  d  dd  e  f  g  gg  r  t  z
0  2  1  1   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1   0  0  1  1   0  0  0  1
2  0  0  0   0  1  0  0   0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0   2  0  1  1   1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the code is giving me an error. The error is as follows "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'stack'".

Comment: @M.Nair I was missing a closing bracket. It should’ve thrown a syntax error. Check my edit.